# Is it possible to stream input from the console using readline? (Node.js, JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a conditional array ARR, and I want to write values to it in one line

I tried to do it like this

```
import * as readline from 'node:readline/promises';
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from 'process';

const rl = readline.createInterface({input, output})

let arr =[]
console.log('Enter Values: ')
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     arr[i] = await rl.question('')
```

But when I do this, I get a line-by-line input:

```
    Enter Values:
    1
    A
    2
    B
```

And I need to:

```
   Enter Values: 1 A 2 B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readline` separates the input stream by newlines, but you want to separate it by spaces. The following transform stream accomplishes that. Note it is consumed with `for await (...) {}` rather than `for (...) { await }`.

```js
var input = new stream.Transform({
  readableObjectMode: true,
  transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    this.buffer = this.buffer ?
      Buffer.concat([this.buffer, chunk], this.buffer.length + chunk.length) :
      chunk;
    while (true) {
      var offset = this.buffer.indexOf(" ");
      if (offset === -1) break;
      this.push(this.buffer.toString("utf8", 0, offset));
      while (this.buffer[offset + 1] === 0x20) offset++;
      this.buffer = this.buffer.slice(offset + 1);
    }
    callback();
  }
});
console.log('Enter Values: ');
process.stdin.pipe(input);
let arr = [];
let i = 0;
for await (var number of input) {
  arr[i] = number;
  i++;
  if (i >= 5) break;
}
console.log(arr);
```